# Featured Images Not Loading In Blog Archives

Tags: post-thumbnails, archives

A client running a custom theme recently updated their WordPress version from 5.2.7 to 5.7.1. After this update, featured images in blog archives are no longer loading.

The theme has been updated to be compatible with the latest WordPress release and is throwing no errors.

To be clear, the markup is there -- we have the img tag loading with all necessary data (class, src, srcset, etc.). It's just that the image itself won't load, as though it's missing from the server. I've tried removing the featured image, setting a new featured image, and uploading a new featured image. I've even tried such a simple thing as clearing my cache, but nothing gets the image to load.

I know this will simply be outdated code, but I'm struggling to locate the precise issue. Featured images are enabled with `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` and the image is retrieved with `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' );`.

I've tried regenerating thumbnails with [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) in case of any errors, with no success.

Any insight as to how this can be corrected would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the image load outside of WP?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: @vancoder Yes, the image loads normally when accessed directly.

Comment: @RobertWent There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Can you add a link to the site so we can take a look? Sounds like a css issue.

Comment: @RobertWent It turns out it was as simple as a CSS issue, as you suggest. I hadn't caught it earlier, but it was a `display: flex;` causing the problem. Unsure of its original purpose, but removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @RobertWent, it was a simple matter of a CSS issue.

A rogue `display: flex;` on the image container was the troublemaker, and once removed, the issue was resolved.